# DataSet Tables Not Populating

Tags: c#, sql, datatable, dataset

I'm relatively new to using DataSets and DataTables in Visual Studio, and am currently trying to populate a DataTable to query for a SQL Insert statement. What I'm using right now is this.

```
            string query = "USE [Database] SELECT e.ID, e.FieldTypeDesc, e.FieldTypeNum, e.tblFieldRefID, f.TableName, f.RefColumn, f.ColumnName FROM tblEnum e JOIN tblFieldRef f  ON e.tblFieldRefID = f.ID;";

            string field0; //field0 - field12 declared

            SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection();
            conn.ConnectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DatabaseConnectionString"].ConnectionString;
            conn.Open();

            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, conn);

            MRWPDataSet1 dsMRWP = new MRWPDataSet1();
            SqlCommand cmdMRWP = new SqlCommand(query, conn);

            SqlDataAdapter daMRWP = new SqlDataAdapter();
            daMRWP.SelectCommand = cmdMRWP;
            daMRWP.Fill(dsMRWP);
```

Which all seems to work as planned. When I get to this part, though...

```
            foreach (DataRow drMRWP in dsMRWP.Tables[0].Rows)
            {
                field0 = drMRWP["Field0"].ToString();
                field1 = drMRWP["Field1"].ToString(); //for field0 - field12

                string update = "INSERT INTO [dbo].[Table] ([Code], [Description], [SendEmail], [Type], [CustomForeColor], [Inactive], [ModifiedDate], [CreatedDate], [ModifiedById], [CreatedById], [StartDate], [EndDate]) VALUES (field1, field2, field3, field4, field5, field5, field6, field7, field8, field9, field10, field11, field12)";
                SqlCommand upd = new SqlCommand(update, conn);
            }
```

it is skipped entirely, with apparently no values stored in drMRWP. It isn't even stepped into in debugging, just stepped over.

I'm new to all of this, so chances are I overlooked something or made a mistake somewhere, but damned if I can see what it might be. Any insight offered toward that, or suggestions to simplify what might otherwise be overly-complicated, sloppy code would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Since you are using a strongly typed `DataSet` i assume that it contains multiple tables. So either use a "normal" `DataSet` and keep using `Tables[0]` or use the correct table which is an autogenerated type deriving from `DataTable`.

For example (presuming the auto generated type of the table is `tblEnum`):

```
foreach (DataRow drMRWP in dsMRWP.tblEnum)
{
    // ...
}
```

It also has strongly typed `DataRows` which additional properties you'll lose if you cast it to `DataRow` in the `foreach`. So replace `DataRow` with `tblEnumRow`(the name is derived from the table-name).

Comment: The DataTable in MRWPDataSet1 is identical to what's called in `query`, at the very beginning. Should I reference it at all? Should I use `DataSet dsMRWP = new DataSet();` or `foreach (DataRow drMRWP in dsMRWP.DataTable1.Rows)` or am I missing what you're getting at? Sorry for the ignorance; like I said, I'm still really new to this.

Comment: @Eiketsu: you can use both. Since you already have the typed `DataSet` i would use that.

Comment: Tried using `foreach (DataRow drMRWP in dsMRWP.DataTable1)` and tblEnum and tblFieldRef but it's still skipping past everything.

Comment: @Eiketsu: what happens if you use a plain `DataSet`/`DataTable`? If you fill a typed DataSet you normally(ever?) use the appropriate `TableAdapter` which is sittng in it's own namespace which name is derived from the DataSet and ends with `...TableAdapters`(so probably `dsMRWPTableAdapters`). Try to use their `Fill` methods.

Comment: When I debug and get to `field0 = drMRWP["Field0"].ToString();` in the `foreach`, I get "An unhandled exception of type 'System.ArgumentException' occurred in System.Data.dll

Additional information: Column 'Field0' does not belong to table Table."

As for the `TableAdapter` I found `namespace MRWPAutosys.MRWPDataSet1TableAdapters` to reference, but I'm not quite following what you're suggesting I use it for.

Comment: @Eiketsu: you have said that it's "still skipping past everything" which means that the table is empty, isn't it? Of course there is no `Field0` column, have a look at your sql to see which means you have. If you want the first field use `drMRWP[0]` instead.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/66606/discussion-between-tim-schmelter-and-eiketsu).